# How to sync laravel storage folders on multiple servers

Tags: laravel, deployment, scaling

I have a laravel application which is deployed in three servers and load balancer is configured to handle requests to those three servers. How do I manage the storage folders for logs and other things between those application servers

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution for this?

Comment: Well I kept logs in logstash and use rsync to sync the files